# Not able to change the value of a data-frame column using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

```
for ind in data6.index:
    if(data6['Label'][ind]>0):
        data6['Label'][ind]=1
        
data6
```

***I am trying to set values greater than equal to 1 in the data-frame to 1***

[image]

**The error I am getting is:**

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is
> trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> data6['Label'][ind]=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked**

```
data6['Label'].values[data6['Label'].values > 0] = 1
data6
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of the way you are accessing the DataFrame:
I dont know too much about the behaviour of pandas, but it sometimes returns a slice as a copy and sometimes as a part of the dataframe itself. Using loc and iloc should fix the Problem:

```
import pandas as pd
base_dict = {'data': [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]],
             'Label': [0,4,1]}

data6 = pd.DataFrame(base_dict)

print(data6)

for ind in data6.index:
    if data6.iloc[ind,1] > 0:
        data6.iloc[ind,1] = 1
        
print(data6)
```

If you are intrested in why this error occurs, go and read about what pandas slicing returns in which cases.

Comment: Thanks, man it worked as well although I checked myself and have answered below, do check that as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me :

```
df.loc[df["label"] > 0] = 1
```

Input :
[image]

Output :
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy, I have answered below and there is another one on the thread, do check that as well.